# To get latest USN between all domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, replication, domaincontroller, usn

Is it possible to get latest USN between all domain controllers ?

```
Get-ADReplicationUpToDatenessVectorTable -Target "domain.com" |
select LastReplicationSuccess, Server, USNFilter | 
Sort-Object -Property LastReplicationSuccess -Descending |  Format-Table
```

```
(Get-ADDomainController).HostName | 
Get-ADReplicationUpToDatenessVectorTable -Scope Server | 
select LastReplicationSuccess, Server, USNFilter | 
Sort-Object -Property LastReplicationSuccess -Descending |  Format-Table
```

The output only showing for same domain controller host.